# How to prove that is not a regular surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

In reference to this question:

[This equation define a regular surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991220/this-equation-define-a-regular-surface)

How can I prove that the union of this three plane is not a regular surface?

Intuitively this is clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove a regular surface must at every point locally be a graph of some function over an open set in $xy$ or $yz$ or $xz$ plane.

Consider the origin and argue it can't be a graph of any function ( since it's multi-valued).